# embed google calendar on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Hello I'm trying to embed a Google calendar on my google app script but I am not able to do it. I'm trying to use the html code generated by the calendar but not this working. Someone can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. You can not have `iframes` inside Apps Script webapps. If you're embedding your script in a Google Site, you could workaround by embedding the calendar directly on the site as well.